# Determine Android device performance programmatically

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin

I want to run different lines of code for android devices with different performance. For example something like this:

```
if (isHighPerformanceDevice()) {
    // run code for devices with high performance
} else if (isMediumPerformanceDevice()) {
    // run code for devices with medium performance
} else {
    // run code for devices with low performance
}
```

Or at least:

```
if (isHighPerformanceDevice()) {
    // run code for devices with high performance
} else {
    // run code for devices with low performance
}
```

I wonder if there is something in `Android SDK` I can use or those methods should be implemented manually? I would appreciate any guidance on this, thank you.

Devices with **Android 10** and higher.

Comment: How about you check their RAM size and maybe their CPU core types?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I thought about it. `CPU core types` did you mean CPU core count?

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/using-performance-class-to-optimize.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer you to get the drive performance using its RAM.

To get RAM values simply do:

```
ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    assert actManager != null;
    actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
    long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem;
    long availMemory = memInfo.availMem;
    long usedMemory = totalMemory - availMemory;
    float precentlong = (((float) (availMemory / totalMemory)) * 100);
```

Here you will get Total as well as Free and Used RAM size.
The value of these will be in "long", so format it to human-readable (i.e in MB/GB).
Use the following method to do so:

```
 private String floatForm(double d) {
    return String.format(java.util.Locale.US, "%.2f", d);
}

private String bytesToHuman(long size) {
    long Kb = 1024;
    long Mb = Kb * 1024;
    long Gb = Mb * 1024;
    long Tb = Gb * 1024;
    long Pb = Tb * 1024;
    long Eb = Pb * 1024;

    if (size < Kb) return floatForm(size) + " byte";
    if (size >= Kb && size < Mb) return floatForm((double) size / Kb) + " KB";
    if (size >= Mb && size < Gb) return floatForm((double) size / Mb) + " MB";
    if (size >= Gb && size < Tb) return floatForm((double) size / Gb) + " GB";
    if (size >= Tb && size < Pb) return floatForm((double) size / Tb) + " TB";
    if (size >= Pb && size < Eb) return floatForm((double) size / Pb) + " Pb";
    if (size >= Eb) return floatForm((double) size / Eb) + " Eb";

    return "0";
}
```

Now you can customise this code to your needs. I can't say that 1 Pb RAM is hight performance or low performance in your case. It depends on what your app does. That is the thing u need to do